# Как называетя анимация линий CSS

Tags: html, css

Как называется анимация в виде двигающихся линий css[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос странный. Хочется найти эту анимацию или что?

Comment: Как называется данная технология, где обычно делают подобные анимации. Если будет пример, будет намного лучше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рисуются подобные анимации скорее всего в canvas. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

Сама анимация из вопроса похожа на https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Comment: Не скорее всего, а лучше всего)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 чем принципиально лучше SVG?

Comment: @andreymal, ниразу не видел подобного реализованного на svg, обычно на канвасе.